# New coder, trying to make Label invisible on program start

Tags: c#, visible

First, pardon my new-ness, I just started coding class recently. Now, upon startup, I want parts of my form (c#) to not be shown, however when I put

```
    NameDisplay.Visible = false;
```

(NameDisplay being the label I wish to hide) into my Form1.cs it gives me the error of that it is a 'field' being used as a 'type'. How do I correct this, and apply to other object types (buttons, textboxes, etc?)

EDIT 1-
Code- as it stands

```
    namespace ATM
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
     Label NameDisplay;
     NameDisplay.Visible = false;


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void NameDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
     private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


}
```

}

Comment: Where do you have this code? Is it within a constructor?

Comment: show the code where `NameDisplay` is defined/declared ... I guess you need `nameDisplay` (lower case n)

Comment: @Andrew Valenta, Post your UI code

Comment: It is a *statement*, not a declaration.  It belongs in the constructor.  Along with the other code you need to create the Label object, set its properties and add it to the Controls collection.  The code that InitializeComponent normally takes care of.  Have a look-see at it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Label NameDisplay;`, and place `NameDisplay.Visible = false;` into your `FormLoad` event.

The loading of a form is an event just like clicking a button, and will execute the code like so.

Also, when I hide labels, I use `.Hide()`, but I believe that only works on WinForms.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

- You need to drag and drop the Label on the form and object will be created and initialized automatically in InitializeComponent.
- In the form constructor (after InitializeComponent function) or Form_Load event, you may set the visibility to false

For example:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NameDisplay.Visible = false;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void NameDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```